# Allocation for RenderScript gives error even though the size should be adequate

Tags: android, renderscript, google-project-tango, android-renderscript

I am trying to use the built in RenderScript script for converting NV21 to RGBA8888, but even thoguh I checked the size of the buffer in the Allocation object I still got the following error:
`Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x4eb30000 (code=1), thread 18458 (epthsyncexample)`

My code:

```
 rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    yuvToRgbIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));


    Type.Builder yuvType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8_4(rs))
            .setX(1280).setY(720)
            .setYuvFormat(android.graphics.ImageFormat.NV21);
    Allocation in = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    in.copyFrom(YUVArray); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


    Type.Builder rgbaType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8_4(rs))
            .setX(W).setY(H);
    Allocation out = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbaType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

    byte[] RGBOut = new byte[W * H * 4];

    //

    yuvToRgbIntrinsic.setInput(in);
    yuvToRgbIntrinsic.forEach(out);

    out.copyTo(RGBOut);
    return RGBOut;
```

The error itself is easy to understand, but why it happens I do not know. The byte array I use to represent the NV21 image is of size 1382400 bytes. The Allocation buffer is of 1280*720*1.5 = 1382400 bytes. I dont understand why the marked line of code caused a segmentation fault.

Any hints?

I have read some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037029/how-work-properly-with-array-allocations-in-renderscript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805168/memory-errors-using-allocations-and-renderscript), but they are about completely different problems. The only question that might have something to do with it is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265108/processing-1920x1280-image-with-android-renderscript). Where can I find out about this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of meddling with the code I realized what was causing the problem. When I was debugging through the code I must have caused some race conditions or something because every time I load data to and from the unit I had a high chance of getting a seg fault.

The code that I ended up with that works IF ALLOWED TO RUN passed the RenderScript segment was:

```
public byte[] convertYUV2RGB(byte[] YUVArray, int H, int W){//W: 1280, H: 720

    //Convert using the premade script here.
    rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    yuvToRgbIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));

    Type.Builder yuvType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs)).setX(YUVArray.length);

    Allocation in = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

    Type.Builder rgbaType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs)).setX(W).setY(H);

    Allocation out = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbaType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    in.copyFrom(YUVArray);
    byte[] RGBOut = new byte[W * H * 4];

    yuvToRgbIntrinsic.setInput(in);
    yuvToRgbIntrinsic.forEach(out);

    out.copyTo(RGBOut);
    return RGBOut;
}
```